# Understanding Android app installation process PackageManagerService.installPackage

Tags: android, message-queue, sendmessage, native-code, android-package-managers

I'm trying to track how an app is being installed from start and so far I've been able to trace the source code where the call goes to PackageManagerService which extends the PackageManager and calls the method installPackageWithVerification(), the code for which is shown below for reference:

```
@Override
    public void installPackageWithVerification(Uri packageURI, IPackageInstallObserver observer, int flags, String installerPackageName, Uri verificationURI, ManifestDigest manifestDigest) {

        mContext.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES, null);

        final int uid = Binder.getCallingUid();

        final int filteredFlags;

        if (uid == Process.SHELL_UID || uid == 0) {
            if (DEBUG_INSTALL) {
                Slog.v(TAG, "Install from ADB");
            }
            filteredFlags = flags | PackageManager.INSTALL_FROM_ADB;
        } else {
            filteredFlags = flags & ~PackageManager.INSTALL_FROM_ADB;
        }

            final Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(INIT_COPY);
            msg.obj = new InstallParams(packageURI, observer, filteredFlags, installerPackageName,
                    verificationURI, manifestDigest);
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
```

The last 3 lines of code above create a message handler object and basically encapsulates the package install params in the message and sends it. I'm not clearly sure where the message gets delivered.

I went and debugged the android.os.Handler which basically defines the sendMessage(), all i can find is this message gets added to the a queue natively using the instance of android.os.MessageQueue

Could someone kindly enlighten me on what happens next to the package? or even the message en-queued in the NativeMessageQueue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search for `InstallParams` in the AOSP code, and you'll find the spot. Or find out where `mHandler` comes from and where the `handleMessage` is implemented.

Comment: I got that figured out. mHandler is a PackageHandler class (which extends android.os.Handler class) defined in the service itself. As I mentioned sendMessage method in android.os.Handler adds the message to the MessageQueue. And that's where I'm stuck, unable to figure out what happens next!

Comment: That's where you have to figure out where `mHandler` comes from -- this `Handler` will handle the message you sent it.

Comment: Yes I missed it there is a handleMessage in the mHandler as you pointed out.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I've got it figured out. My bad the PackageHandler is defined somewhere on top in the same file. Its hard to find when you are browsing through file with 3K lines of code :-P